# How reorder working sets in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, working-set

I just upgraded to Eclipse Indigo. It appears that some working set functionality is missing. How do I change the order of the working sets in the Project Explorer window? In Helios I could just drag and drop.

A second, but related question: What happened to the default Other Projects working set? Now when I create a project I have to explicitly add it to a selected working set or I can't see it. Before, it would just show up in the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that in the previous version of Eclipse I was using the PackageExplorer, not the Project Explorer. Go to Window / Show View / Package Explorer and all is right with the world.